The file names are changing in the Build file.But because it caches, changes are not initially reflected on the page, they come if I refresh the page
Since the package version will change when I make changes, am I doing something right if I keep the version value in local storage, compare it for each new cache update, and refresh the page accordingly?
  const localVersion = localStorage.getItem('appVersion'); 
  const checkAndUpdateVersion = () => { 
  const serverVersion = packageJson.version; 
  if (serverVersion) {
   if (localVersion !== packageJson.version) { 
        localStorage.setItem('appVersion', serverVersion); 
        window.location.reload(); 
      }
     }
    }; 

